# Track by phone gps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to figure out where to start. I have a friend that I'm building a website for and I'd like to basically track a mobile location on a website using javascript. I would like to show when ever a possible customer comes to the website I want to show all employees on the road at that time. I just need to know where to start. I'll figure out the rest. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
});
```

this will return a coordinates object for the current position. Or if you want to continuously update the users position you can use

```
var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
  do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
});
```

and then stop the watch with

`navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);`

I have used these for a location based web game before, more info here: 
[MDN Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation)

edit: just remember it is asynchronous, so all the work you want to do with the position object must be done in the callback function.

Comment: How would I get the continuous location of mobile device. Maybe through mobile id? How would I get that. This is not to track customers, but employees location at all times.